# Load exception while getting string javafx fxml

Tags: java, javafx, parameter-passing, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm trying to pass a simple String to a new java file but I get an error stating
`JavaFX.fxml.LoadException:`

Where `moveId` is a `public String` in main.java, 
 and the method `updateEvent` is called on a button click event (`onClick`)

## Main.Java

```
public void updateEvent(ActionEvent event) {
try{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoad = new 
    FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("change_relocationDetails.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoad.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setTitle("Update Relocation Details Of : "+moveID);
    stage.show();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

   }        
 }


public String get_MoveId(){

        return moveID;
    }

 private boolean validateID() {

   moveID=move_id.getText();

 }
```

## Change_relocationDetailsController.java

```
public class Change_relocationDetailsController implements Initializable {

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
public String moveID;
@FXML
private TextField move_id;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO

    ChangeOrDeleteController change_delete = new  ChangeOrDeleteController();
  moveID = change_delete.get_MoveId();
   move_id.setDisable(true);

    }    

 }
```

## Full stacktrace

```
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at pp01_cwk03.ChangeOrDeleteController.updateEvent(ChangeOrDeleteController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pp01_cwk03.ChangeOrDeleteController.get_MoveId(ChangeOrDeleteController.java:79)
    at pp01_cwk03.Change_relocationDetailsController.initialize(Change_relocationDetailsController.java:33)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: This could be caused by the fxml or by some error during the `initialize` method call. Post the full stack trace instead of catching the exception and simply printing the result of the `toString` method... You need to modify the try/catch for this. Furthermore we may need the fxml. My best bet is that this is caused by a NPE in the `initialize` method of the controller...

Comment: These codes failed to tell us how `moveID` relates to the whole thing. We don't even know the exception is related to the `moveID` in `main.java` or the `move_id` in `Change_relocationDetailsController` or `ChangeOrDeleteController`. Like what fabian said, we need you to do `e.printStackTrace()`,

Comment: @Jai I updated the question with a printStackTrace. moveID is just a user inputted String

Comment: Please, ensure that the code you are actually executing is the same you have posted. Clean up your project, compile it all again, and re-execute. I insist, because the stacktrace you posted says NPE at `get_MoveId(ChangeOrDeleteController.java:79)`, which is nonsense, because simply returning a String can not produce a NPE.

Comment: I can not find your `ChangeOrDeleteController` .